# Installation of PuTTY on Mac-Mojave

Tags: macos, installation, unix, putty, macos-mojave

I downloaded PuTTY as given in this https://www.puttygen.com/download-putty .
And I got a Unix executable file and as soon as I click on it I am getting an error:

```
(process:5149): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:09:33.715: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.

(PuTTY:5149): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:09:33.734: cannot open display: 
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

My locale are set as follows:

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL="C"
```

Can someone please help me how can I resolve this error? and move forward to my PuTTY configuration window.

Comment: Do you specifically need PuTTY? MacOS already comes with an SSH client (OpenSSH).

Comment: I was learning was from a course where I needed it. I am newbie so please can you let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The messages about the "locale" settings shouldn't matter. It ought to work without it using the "fallback" locale.

But:
Putty for Mac requires X11 which is no longer part of OSX on the newer MacOS versions.
The "Can't open display" error message refers most likely to that problem.

You will need to install the [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) system which is the (open source) successor to the X11.app.

Comment: I did download it. Can you please let me know the further process that I will have to do?

Comment: Download thw XQuatz.DMG file, open it. Run the installer (XQuartz.pkg) and follow the prompts. After teh install you will need to logout/login (or reboot) to have it active. That should be all there is to it. It will be automatically run whenever an X11 program (like PuTTY) needs it.

Comment: Ok. I will try and update you on the same.

Comment: Thank you. Thanks a lot. It's working now.